# Android studio My app is displaying incorrectly.

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to learn to make my own apps by following tutorials but i have an issue when i run the app in the emulator or on my phone. All the[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca4kp.png) contents of the layout are squished in the top left corner.

This is all the code[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCKDe.png)here. I am a noob so don't go to hard on me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you also post your layout code (activity_main.xml) here for this kind of problems. But I am guessing you are using constraint layout as root of your layout and its child views are not constrained vertically, so all of them go to another position in run time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a relative layout and no positioning is specified.

You should paste the xml's code